# get field by name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to create a function that can return a field from its object.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public class Base
{
    public string thing = "Thing";
    public T GetAttribute<T>(string _name)
    {
        return (T)typeof(T).GetProperty(_name).GetValue(this, null);
    }
}
```

What I would ideally like is to call:

```
string thingy = GetAttribute<string>("thing");
```

but I have a feeling I got the wrong end of the stick when reading up on this because I keep getting null reference exceptions.

Comment: Use the following answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Note that in C#, the term 'attribute' has a specific meaning: it's a piece of meta-data that can be attached to classes or methods, among other things. That's not what your question is about - the correct terms would be that you're using 'reflection' to get the value of a 'field' or 'property'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First thing - `thing` is a field, not a property.

Another thing is that you have to change parameter type to get it working:

```
public class Base {

   public string thing = "Thing";

   public T GetAttribute<T> ( string _name ) {
      return (T)typeof(Base).GetField( _name ).GetValue (this, null);
   }   
}
```

BTW - you can get property/field value by referencing an instance:

```
var instance = new Base();
var value = instance.thing;
```

Comment: thank you very much, that works a charm! i have only one issue, which is my fault for not mentioning before, Base is going to be inherited by other things, is there a way to say a kind of " typeof ( this ) " type thing?

Comment: thanks for the BTW too, i know this seems highly illogical but there is a very long and complicated reason for needing this, i wont go into it :)

Comment: @inadequateMonkey  use `this.GetType()` instead of `typeof(Base)`

Answer (score 8):

`thing` is a field not a property. You should use `GetField` method instead of `GetProperty`.
Another problem is you are looking in `typeof(T)`. You should look for the field in `typeof(Base)`.

The whole function should be changed to

```
public T GetAttribute<T>(string _name)
{
    return (T)GetType().GetField(_name).GetValue(this);
}
```

If you want to have an extension method to get field value of a type  you can use this

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static TFieldType GetFieldValue<TFieldType, TObjectType>(this TObjectType obj, string fieldName)
    {
        var fieldInfo = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return (TFieldType)fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
var b = new Base();
Console.WriteLine(b.GetFieldValue<string, Base>("thing"));
```

Using `BindingFlags` will help you to get field value even if it is private or static field.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for downvote so I can improve my answer?

Comment: This solves only a part of a problem - there are clearly problems with parameter type.

Comment: thanks, i changed it to : return (T) typeof( T ).GetField ( _name ).GetValue ( this ); but still no joy

Comment: `return (T)typeof(Base).GetField(_name).GetValue(this);` should probably be `return (T)GetType().GetField(_name).GetValue(this);` - since you're explicitly passing `this` in. Otherwise, it will break when trying to access fields/properties of the sub class (if any).